# Desktop remote control unable to access my account

Tags: login, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to access via remote desktop (with VNC since RDP doesn't work...) to my work account. On my work computer there are 4 accounts and every time I try to login, it logs me in to an account different from mine (that isn't admin) and I'm not able to change account.

I tried to open my account on the computer and then logging in by remote and again, it show me the desktop of the same other user.

How could this be? Is it possible that, being some process active on the other account, it redirects me there? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please give more info about what ubuntu version you are using, what vnc server program and with what commands/options you start vnc server. Assuming your work computer is using ubuntu 15.04 or latest and x11vnc, you can use the option `-auth guess` to the x11vnc command which will enable you to be able to logout and login again with a different account as it is described here:
http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html under the section `-auth file`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and the standard Remmina remote desktop VNC...

Comment: What about your work computer? What vnc server are you using? Is it x11vnc or vino? How you did you make it start at boot (with what script and what commands)? Is it the same as described here: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8361 (ubuntu 15.10 works the same)?

Comment: Now xrdp works, it had problems with something graphical and I found a command line that make it works!